# What is the appropriate usage of these profiling switches?

Tags: gcc, g++, profiling, compiler-flags

I'm still pretty new to GCC and I'm wondering how exactly do I use certain profiling switches.

I've read the GCC manual entries for `-ftree-loop-ivcanon` and `-fivopts` (neither of which are implied by `-fprofiled-generate/use`) and while I have a (relatively) good idea of what they do I don't know where I should use them or if I should use them at all.

Should I use the flags in a combined compilation?

`g++ Example.cxx -o Example.exe -Wall -ftree-loop-ivcanon -fivopts`

A compilation only?

`g++ Example.cxx -o Example.o -c -Wall -ftree-loop-ivcanon -fivopts`

Or a linking only?

`g++ Example.o -o Example.exe -Wall -ftree-loop-ivcanon -fivopts`

Should I only use these flags when profiling is enabled or can I use them with -On?

And lastly if I do use these when profiling should I use them with the generate switch or the use switch, or both?

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge You can use these at compilation only.

Answer (score 0):

`-ftree-loop-ivcanon` and `-fivopts` only affect compilation, not linking, but I'm pretty sure they don't do anything unless you enable optimisation, with at least `-O`.

You probably don't need to use them, just use `-O` or `-O2` or `-O3` instead of tweaking individual or more-specific options, unless you know exactly what you're trying to achieve and are measuring the precise effects.

If you're trying to use profile-guided optimisation then you definitely want to use `-O` or a higher optimisation level - it's a complete waste of time optimising based on profile data if you're not even enabling basic optimisations such as inlining and constant propagation.

Comment: But in gcc -O0 is the default optimization, so there is no need to specify optiization if you dont need specific one.

Comment: @neel, I'm not sure what you mean, but `-O0` disables all optimisation passes.["Most optimizations are only enabled if an -O level is set on the command line. Otherwise they are disabled, even if individual optimization flags are specified."](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)